# OMNeT++ Error in Module

Tags: routes, protocols, omnet++, inet

I am working on a project where I need to implement a routing protocol for VANET. I am using the INET Framework to implement the modules and VEINS to connect SUMO and OMNeT++.

When I run my simulation I am getting this error:

**Error in module (inet::physicallayer::Ieee80211Radio)** ManhattanScenario.RoadSideUnit.nic.radio (id=51) **during network initialization: Module not found on path** 'radioMedium' **defined by par** 'ManhattanScenario.RoadSideUnit.nic.radio.radioMediumModule'.

Thank You in advace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You most likely forgot to place a Ieee80211ScalarRadioMedium (named radioMedium) module in the top-level network so the radios in the mobile/RSU nodes cannot find it.